# Regex to convert some variables to js

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression for converting variables to js. They can be number or varchar. I want to replace them as seen on below.

```
myNumber number;      ---->    var myNumber = null;
x varchar2(10);       ---->    var x = null;
str varchar2(20);     ---->    var str = null;
```

Is it possible to do it with replace and regex?

Comment: It's possible. What have you tried?

Comment: This question is too vague. Your examples are not sufficient to write code.

Answer (score 1):

You need this:

```
function convert(s) {
    return s.replace(/(\w+).*/g, 'var $1 = null;');
}
```

Usage:

```
convert('myNumber number'); // returns "var myNumber = null;"
```

Comment: Usage? `convert("myNumber number;")` return `undefined`, because of the missing `return` statement.

Comment: @TanyaRai Are you really looking for a `abc varchablabla;` to `var abc = null;` replacement method? Sergei, your code is missing a global flag.

Comment: Yes Rob W, just like you tell. abc varchablabla; to var abc = null; Could you help?

Comment: @SergeiTulentsev I have edited your answer. *Now* it's working correctly (the `/g` global flag is necessary to match more than one line).

Comment: Hmm, I didn't know multiline matching works this way. Thanks :-)

Comment: Thank you; and one more thing. What if there is an assigment? Ex: str varchar2(10):='Example';  --->  var str='Example';

Comment: @TanyaRai: It's called changing requirements. It pisses us (developers) off. :-) You can take this code and modify it yourself, now that you know how it's done.

Comment: You're right but i'm sure its very simple to you. I don't understand the mechanics of regex. Could you help?

Comment: I could, but I won't. This is your chance to start learning. I won't always be there.

Comment: @TanyaRai You have to define the strict requirements before asking a question. For example, what's the format of the input? Are multiline ariables allowed?

Comment: You're right; but it's my first question as you see. Thanks for your understanding. I hope you help me about new requirements. No  multiline ariables allowed, input may be integer or string.